# Does Machine Vision API work offline?

Tags: android-vision

Does the Google Mobile Vision (https://developers.google.com/vision/) API work offline? Or does it need Internet connectivity? The [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/ocr-reader/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) does not require any Internet permission. Which means the API works entirely offline. I am looking for a positive confirmation of this.

PS. Also I am looking for more information on this API. For example, does it use neural networks? If so what algorithms were used? I can not find any detail discussion anywhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The API does an initial library download the first time that it is used, and then works offline from that point on.

Comment: What is a size of the lib? And which location will it be stored?

Comment: Yes, I also think the Api works on online mode.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the official sample app [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/).

I installed the sample app on a device **in airplane mode**, and continued to run under airplane mode - It works without problem.
(Note that I only tested the OCR part)

But as far as I know, all google services libraries made use of an already installed (On most device, probably, except China models) application named `Google Play Services`. As long as this application is installed in the device (With a reasonably updated version), the Vision API should works even under no internet connectivity.