# Is it possible to use Google vision API offline in Python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client, google-vision

I have a simple Python application which uses Google vision API. How can I make it to work offline? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832882/does-machine-vision-api-work-offline)  is about android app and it seems that for that case the answer is positive. Here is my code:

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json')
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=credentials)
with io.open('my_figure.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
     content = image_file.read()
image_context = types.ImageContext(language_hints =["en"])
image = types.Image(content=content)
response = client.text_detection(image=image, image_context=image_context)
texts = response.text_annotations
for text in texts:
  print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))
```

Comment: Well, web services aren't really meant to work offline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Machine Vision API work offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832882/does-machine-vision-api-work-offline)

Comment: [Does Machine Vision API work offline?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832882/does-machine-vision-api-work-offline) is about android app.